# Jetpack and wordpress.com showing incorrect stats after copying website

Tags: php, wordpress, jetpack

I've copied website from ColoradoCarShow.com to ArizonaCarShow.com 
Now both are different websites situated on different server.

Problem is ColoradoCarShow.com is showing blank stats(or fresh status) and ArizonaCarShow.com which is new website is showing stats of ColoradoCarShow.com which is older website on Jetpack and on Wordpress.com.

Stats of both websites are interchanged, can anyone tell me solution for this issue?

Comment: What method did you use for your copy? Was it a migration tool?

Comment: I have use wordpress backup plugin to take backup, after that I've uploaded/copy it on a new server.